# three.js switching objects visibility on and off through GUI

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking to turn objects in my scene on/off through the click of a button on a gui. 
I have the function:

```
g3white.traverse(function(child){child.visible = true;});
g3black.traverse(function(child){child.visible = false;});
```

This function successfully hides/shows each object manually.

However, I want to set this to an onChange function to show the black one and hide the white one (and vice versa) with the click of a button.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the `java` tag, since it doesn't look like you're using Java at all.

Comment: Downvoted this because question does not show any effort of the author at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DAT.Gui](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui)

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();

var controls = {

  toggleObjects: function(){
    g3white.traverse(function(child){child.visible = true;});
    g3black.traverse(function(child){child.visible = false;});
  }

};

gui.add(controls, 'toggleObjects');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually tried that same exact function as well as onChange and none of them work. I continue getting the following errors:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
update 
animate

As well as:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'traverse' of undefined index3.html:180
controls.toggleObjects index3.html:180
b.extend.fire dat.gui.min.js:24
(anonymous function) dat.gui.min.js:23
f.fakeEvent dat.gui.min.js:9
(anonymous function)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Sounds like variable scope issues to me ; make sure the object on which you call `animate`, and your `g3white`/`g3black` objects are well defined in the scope you call them.